# Table lags at 100% width

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, html-table

I have a table with a large number of elements, I want the table to stretch to the full width of the screen. The problem is that when it stretches, it starts to slow down terribly.
[image]
however, if you set the table to a fixed width or reduce it to the width of the appearance of the bottom scroll, then everything works correctly and there are no lags
[image]
tell me how it can be optimized? maybe it's wrong that I use table tag ?

Comment: No one will be able to help you with pictures only, you need to show some effort (you can add your code to the question)

Comment: use `lazy component` now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a workaround could be to use javascript to trigger the table resize after a delay.

Adding css transition to make it look smooth.

Example:

```js
let delayedResize = null;
window.onresize = (event) => {
    setTableWidth();
};
setTableWidth();
function setTableWidth(){
    clearTimeout(delayedResize);
    delayedResize = setTimeout(() => {
        document.querySelector('table').style.width = window.innerWidth + "px";
    }, 100);
}
```

```css
html,body{
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden
}
table {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    transition: width 0.4s;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>test</td>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you it's good solution to give on every resolution fixed width